# HTML Table moves when resizing window

Tags: html

I have made a HTML table, which is actually the menu on top of the side in the header, positioned right of the logo, but when I resize the window, the table is not fixed and jumps under the logo. I need some help on how to set the table as fixed.

Here is the code:

```html
<div style="float:left">
  <img src="images/grafikalogo.png" style="margin-top: 20px;" />
</div>

<table style="margin-top:-20px; padding-left:10px;" cellspacing="30px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./izracun.php">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Vizitka.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Zgibanke.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Brosure.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Letaki.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Nalepke.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Kuverte.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/dopisni-list.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Letaki.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't concern the question itself, but you should consider using `<div>` or another element instead of `<table>` for referencement issue, as `<table>` element is more likely to be considered as a data holder more than anything.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the table to div, and set a fixed width. It works now, the icons don't move. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is when you resize the window.your object in page are getting in lines that cause the page not to get scrolled,so if you do not whant that to happen.you should use `min-width` CSS for your container,so when ewsizing the container dosent't shrink;

```html
<div style="float:left">
  <img src="images/grafikalogo.png" style="margin-top: 20px;" />
</div>

<table style="margin-top:-20px; padding-left:10px;" cellspacing="30px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./izracun.php">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Vizitka.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Zgibanke.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Brosure.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Letaki.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Nalepke.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Kuverte.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/dopisni-list.png" />
      </a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="./vizitke.html">
        <img style="height:80px; width:80px;" src="images_new/Letaki.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
```